# Defining a function with a loop in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano

I want to define the following function of two variables in Theano and compute its Jacobian:

```
f(x1,x2) = sum((2 + 2k - exp(k*x1) - exp(k*x2))^2, k = 1..10)
```

How do I make a Theano function for the above expression - and eventually minimize it using its Jacobian?

Comment: When saying Jacobian, you mean a determinant of Jacobian matrix?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Theano tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/) yet?

Comment: In particular, take a look at [`scan`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loop.html#scan)

Comment: There is a method to compute the jacobien. The scan documentation show how to do it manually: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/gradient.html#theano.gradient.jacobian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function is scalar, the Jacobian reduces to the gradient. Assuming your two variables `x1, x2` are scalar (looks like it from the formula, easily generalizable to other objects), you can write

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x1 = T.fscalar('x1')
x2 = T.fscalar('x2')

k = T.arange(1, 10)

expr = ((2 + 2 * k - T.exp(x1 * k) - T.exp(x2 * k)) ** 2).sum()

func = theano.function([x1, x2], expr)
```

You can call `func` on two scalars

```
In [1]: func(0.25,0.25)
Out[1]: array(126.5205307006836, dtype=float32)
```

The gradient (Jacobian) is then

```
grad_expr = T.grad(cost=expr, wrt=[x1, x2])
```

And you can use `updates` in `theano.function` in the standard way (see theano tutorials) to make your gradient descent, setting `x1, x2` as shared variables in givens, by hand on the python level, or using `scan` as indicated by others.